# can we inherit `style_one.style_two.style_three` with having `style_one` and no `style_one.style_two` in android style?

Tags: android, inheritance, styles

I have read:

> we have not to use parent attribute. We prefix one style to another
>   style separating by a period(.). Suppose we have a style named as
>   style_one, if we need to inherit it with another style named as
>   style_two, then we can do it as style_one.style_two and if more
>   inheritance needed, suppose for style_three, we can do it as
>   style_one.style_two.style_three. Find the example.

My question is: can we inherit two levels deep when skipping a middleman?

say `style_one.style_two.style_three` with having `style_one` and no `style_one.style_two`

say for future inheritance we want to keep a base `style_two`  but we don't need it at the moment.

I'm asking if I can inherit from a dummy style level, just to keep future hierarchy ?

Comment: If there's the possibility that you're going to have custom style definitions within `style_two` in the future, why not just create a blank `style_two` inheriting from `style_one` now?

Comment: but there is. it's just that `style_two` is empty now

Comment: In which case, if you have a chain of inheritance like `style_one -> style_two -> style_three` I can't imagine any reason why it wouldn't work. Would need to try it out myself though.

Comment: Instead of rewording the same question, you could have edited the first one - as it had no answer. Instead now I've marked the answered post as the duplicate target.

Comment: @YvetteColomb it's not the same question. The title of the old question was wrong. I changed it.